# Window.local message should be retained even if the window is maximized

Tags: visualforce, javascript

In the softphone layout for the CTI integration I am sending the data from visualforce page to other page by using window.local storage. I am able to send the data. But the layout has a maximize button when clicked clears out the data which is stored in the local storage. Kindly let me know how can I retain the data in local storage even when the window is maximized.

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well, so I would like to ask you the following questions:

- Visualforce page and other page share data with window.localStorage rather than sending data?
- Where is the maximize button?
- Is the maximize button registerd some event handler function?